# Retrieving JSON array with $.get but can't set retrieved array value outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I do the following it gives me, in console.log, the values I want.

```
        var q;

        $.get('/ajax_subscribers', { code: 'qyhskkcnd'},
            function(returnedData){
                q = returnedData;
                console.log(q);
            });
```

But if I do this

```
        var q;

        $.get('/ajax_subscribers', { code: 'qyhskkcnd'},
            function(returnedData){
                q = returnedData;
            });

        console.log(q);
```

`q` has no value and is an undefined value? Why can't I set `returnedData` as public?

Comment: `$.get` is an asynchronous call, i.e. it will fire the request and immediately continue on executing the next statements, which in your case is `console.log(q)`. It's clear that your `console.log(q)` is being called way before a response is even returned from the server

Answer (score 0):

`$.get` is asynchronous. You are logging before the ajax is able to finish. In other words, the var q will only have the value once the `$.get` receive the response from the service.

You should handle the returnedData inside the callback function. Or delegate to another function if it's too complex, like:

```
        $.get('/ajax_subscribers', { code: 'qyhskkcnd'},
        function(returnedData){
            doStuffWithReturnedData(returnedData);
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `$.get()` is asynchronous.

To get around that, try setting a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: The link you posted is in French

Comment: My bad, I corrected it.